# Discord.js bot embeds using weighted random choice from an array

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hi I'm creating a discord bot using `discord.js` and `discord.js-commando` and the problem I have is basically trying to make my discord.js bot post an embed with properties below.

Upon running the bot client and typing the command I get an error in my console which says

> (node:6120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

[image: full error starting from bot deployment screenshot]

Previously, the command worked fine before I tried putting the dynamic return outputs (from `answer()`) in the embeds. The `return` value of that function call is a string based on what `lootedItem` is.

`lootedItem` is an object chosen from a weighted random choice of a parent array.

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
     "title": "Game Results",
     "color": 3662439,
     "description": answer(),
     "thumbnail": {
          "url": lootedItem.image
     },
})
message.channel.send('Placing...', {
     embed: embed.setTimestamp()
});
```

Comment: You at some point are trying to get the username of something `Cannot read property 'username' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a field and it requires certain fields to work.

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed({
      "username": "Username",    // you missed this and it is required to work
      "title": "Game Results",
      "color": 3662439,
      "description": answer(),
      "thumbnail": {
          "url": lootedItem.image
    },
})
```